# Plugin Files get changed automatically

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages

My website islamabad.ginyaki.com.
The issue I am facing is that I have customized plugins Foodonlineforwoocomerce, Advanced custom fields. I have disabled plugin and WordPress updates Manually, in functions.php and in wp-config.php but the customized code gets reversed after a few days and starts working as the old or original plugin, I need to know why that's happening and how can i achieve the solution to this problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you editing plugin code? If so auto updates will wipe any edits out....?

Comment: Hello @StevenWillis, I have customized some plugins from developers, The website is working fine but after some days the customized code gets vanished and the plugins get rolled back to default features.